# reactNative: Не могу обработать данные с сервера

Tags: react-native

Как я могу использовать полученное из AsyncStorage значение для кодировки Base64 ?

Сетаю значение из AsyncStorage в state  компонента App (AsyncStorage.setItem() вызываю в thunk, отрабатывает отлично:
значения азписываются в хранилище)

```
class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        userName: "",
        userPassword: ""
    }

getLogin = async () => {

        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("phoneNumber") || 'none'
            if(value !== null) {
                console.log(value , "getLogin");
                this.setState({userName: value}, console.log(this.state.userName, 'getLogin'))
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

getPassword = async () => {

        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("verificationCode") || 'none'
            if(value !== null) {
                console.log(value, "getPassword");
                this.setState({userPassword: value}, console.log(this.state.userPassword, 'getPassword'))
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }


 componentDidMount(){
        this.getLogin()
        this.getPassword()

}
```

В render() App передаю состояние функции

render() {

```
    const {userName, userPassword} = this.state
    getServicesApi(userName, userPassword)
```

}

Далее, использую функцию  getServicesApi для передачи параметров

export function getServicesApi( userName, userPassword) {

```
const base64token = () => {
    if(userName && userPassword) return Base64.btoa(`+${userName}:${userPassword}`)
}
console.log(base64token(), "base64token")

const  headers = () => new Headers({
    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
    "Authorization" : `Basic ${base64token()}`
})
```

}

В итоге console выводит ( undefined, undefined, "base64token" )

Где я допустил ошибку ?  Предположительно, не срабатывает componentDidMount(). Есть ли патерны для решения подобной ситуации ?

Comment: что за вызов функции такой? getServicesApi{userName, userPassword}, почему скобки не те?

Comment: во вторых в componentDidMount везде у каждой функции await надо указать чтобы ждать завершения иначе undefined будет значения во второй функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том, что в методе `componentDidMount` вызываются два асинхронных метода, которые зависят от результатов выполнения друг друга. А так как Вы не указали `await` данные приходят позже чем начинается выполнение другой функции. Результат переменные имеют значение `undefined`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, действительно, для решения задачи нужно было написать await внутри componentDidMount:
<code>
    async componentDidMount(){

        const  login = await getLogin()
        const  password =  await getPassword()
        const isAuth = await getAuth()

        this.setState({isPassword : password})
        this.setState({isLogin: login})
        this.setState({isAuthLocation: isAuth})
        await getServicesApi(login, password)
    }
</code>
Также, помог пост https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970276/is-using-async-componentdidmount-good

Comment: @Dmitry ставьте галочку под ответом (под цифрой слева), чтобы его принять если он Вам помог. Спасибо!